# RTCPeerConnection IOS 12.2 to Android 7.X

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

Im building a RTCPeerConnection communication and I found one issue, calling from iOS 12.2 (Tested with Ipad only) to Android (Tested with 7.11 only) the streams will not exchange.

Other peers is OK, like iOS to Chrome(desktop), iOS to iOS, iOS to Chrome Desktop, Android to iOS is also OK.

Using constraints Audio only works fine with all peers, but the problem occurs when adding Video and the connection goes from iOS 12.2 => Android. (iOS makes an offer)

It may be a codec problem, but Android to iOS establishing a video connection without problem so i'm not sure.

Im using Tracks, not Streams.

Anyone else experience trouble with this and has a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Are you building an iOS app and using the Google SDK? If so, then my guess would be mis-matched `profile-level-id` in the negotiation of H264. If you can, use VP8 and see if you have the same problems.